# Library to help use Guice in Integration Tests

Tags: java, integration-testing, guice

What libraries would you recommend that helps remove boilerplate code, when using Guice from integration tests?

E.g. [AtUnit](http://code.google.com/p/atunit/)

Answer (score 1):

I actually find that Guice boilerplate is fairly minimal in my integration tests.  I keep my modules very small and independent so that I can just tie the ones together that I need for that test and get tends to make the injector creation step quite small as well.  Rather than using an external library i might just use a superclass of a set of JUnit tests to automatically create and inject certain objects that i'm testing.  I'd be interested to hear if any libraries exist to make this easier.